# Difference between Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and Web Developers and for Java EE

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse

The question is, Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and Web Developers and Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, are both different IDEs, right? Assuming that, i can use the tools at Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and Web Developers like a eclipse java EE perspective? If not, what tools i can use to write javascript at Java EE IDE?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: These are both the core Eclipse IDE with a different set of additional plugins added. You can add the JavaScript plugins to the Java install or the Java plugins to the Javascript install from the Eclipse Install New Software dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really always hate to see folks being snippy in their answers, I apologize for the answers you got so far.

The core differences are:

Java:
The essential tools for any Java developer, including a Java IDE, a Git client, XML Editor, Mylyn, Maven and Gradle integration

Web/JavaScript:
The essential tools for any JavaScript developer, including JavaScript, TypeScript, HTML, CSS, XML, Yaml, Markdown... languages support; Kubernetes, Angular and React frameworks support; Node.js debugger; Git client; Mylyn task management; integrated terminal and remote filesystem explorer; Web and application server management.

At the end of the day its all about which packages come pre-installed. You can choose to start with one and then add the packages you want from the other. To see which specific pages are installed with either go here:

Java: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-09/r/eclipse-ide-java-developers

Web/JavaScript: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-09/r/eclipse-ide-web-and-javascript-developers-includes-incubating-components

Answer (score 1):

As the Eclipse site clearly shows, the different versions contain different modules; in this case one has modules for JS and Web development, the other for Java EE development. Just download the version that has all the modules.